# Finding occurrences of element before and after the element in Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a algorithm:

In this algorithm, if an array contains the element `3`, the element `3` cannot be between two `1` elements, like this:

> int array={5, 2, 10, '3', 15, '1', 2, 2} //the ' symbols are just for highlighting the elements in question.

The above array contains the element `3`, and note that before `3` there is no element `1`. 
But after element `3` there is one element `1`, and in this case it should return `True`.
It should return true because the element `3` is not "surrounded" by two elements `1`.

> int array={'3',2,18, >'1' ,0,# 3 #,-11, '1'< ,'3'} //',<,# symbols are just highlighting caracteres.

In this array after first element of `3` there is two elements `1`, surrounding an element `3`, so it should return `False`.

I have tried following code:

```
public class Third 
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        int[] array = {1, 2, 4, 3, 1}; //should return false, '3' contained in '1' elements.

        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i]==3)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<array[i];j++)
                {
                    if(array[j]==1)
                    {

                         System.out.println("I foud One before "+array[j]); 


                    }else
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                        System.out.println("yes i found the array:"+array[i]);
                }

                for(int z=0;z>array[i];z++)
                {
                    if(array[z]==1)
                    {
                             System.out.println("I found after 3 is :"+array[z]);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting exact result from my above code which i want.

Comment: What exactly do you want ?

Comment: defined clearly, read my question again

Comment: I read your question 20 times, I still don't get what you want

Comment: There should no two 1s between 3 in array. for example if array is {5, 2, 10, 3, 15, 1, 2, 2} it should return true. because there are is only one 1 after 3, before 3 there is no 1.

Comment: what happens when there are multiple 3s?

Comment: just left right now multple of 3s, i want to do just now int array={1,2,3,1,2} if this array enterd it will check before 3 is one after 3 is one should return false, if before 3 is one and after 3 is not one should return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, if you are just solely trying to check whether 3 is surrounded by 1s, you can do this. This is according to your question of assuming that you will have no multiple 3s in your array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] array = {3,1,2,4,3,1,3,1};
    int posOfThree = 0;
    int posOfFirstThree = 0;
    boolean noLeft = true;
    boolean noRight = true;
    boolean firstThreeFound = false;
    //Get position of 3
    for (int x=0; x<array.length; x++) 
    {
        if (array[x] == 3)
        {
            if (firstThreeFound == false)
            {   
                posOfFirstThree = x; //Position of the first occurred 3
                firstThreeFound = true;     
            }       
            posOfThree = x;          //Position of the last occurred 3
        }       
    }   

    //Check if there is 1 on left hand side of first 3
    int left = 0;
    while (posOfFirstThree - left > 0)  
    {
        left ++;
        if (array[posOfFirstThree-left] == 1)
            noLeft = false;
    }   

    //Check if there is 1 on right hand side of last 3
    int right = 0;
    while (posOfThree + right < array.length-1) 
    {
        right ++;
        if (array[posOfThree + right] == 1)
            noRight = false;
    }

    System.out.println("Outcome: " + (noLeft || noRight));
}
```

**Program Output:** `Outcome: True`

Since you can only use normal loops and simple array to do this. This is simple enough to suit your requirements. Certainly, I believe this solution can be further improved, however, **this code can get exactly what you need** (even if you increase or decrease the array size).

**EDIT:** The edited version can handle multiple 3s in the array and check whether all 3s are surrounded by 1s.

Comment: if it contains multiple of 3s in array like that int array={3, 2, 18, 1, 0, 3, -11, 1, 3}; Then what condition have to change?

Comment: Then that depends on what you want. Do you only want to check if the middle 3 is surrounded by 1s or you need to check whether all 3s are surrounded by 1s.

Comment: i want to check that No 3 surrounded by 1 , if it surrounded it should return false.

Comment: You mean you want to check each and every 3s in the array?

Comment: That's easy. You just have to check the first encountered 3 and the last encountered 3. If the first and last 3 are surrounded, all the 3s in between are definitely surrounded as well.

Comment: int array[]={3, 2, 18, 1, 0, 3, -11, 1, 3} i want to check this array , this array contain two 3 at array[5] 3 is surrounded with 1 it should return me false.

Comment: I am afraid you have to either edit your question or start a new question, if not I might be voted down for providing you a solution different from your question which is asking to check single 3. You start a new question, I will give you a new solution in your new question.

Comment: i am still on my question, just try to understand me.

Comment: Almost correct , but when i put this array, int[] array = {3,2,18,1,0,3,-11,1,3}; it should return me false but currently on this array i am getting true.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply iterating over the array?:

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> target = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new int[]{1, 3, 1}));
for (int i : array) {
    if (i == 3 || i == 1) {
        nums.add(i);
    }
}
return Collections.indexOfSubList(nums, target) >= 0;
```

Alternatively, with regex:

```
int test[] = {1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 67, 8, 1};
return Arrays.toString(test).matches(".*1.*3.*1.*"); //greedy search
```

Comment: Adding a regex alternative, but why not?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Third {  
 public static void main(String[] args){  
    int[] array = {1,2,4,3, 1}; 

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {

        if(array[i]==3)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            {
                if(array[j]==1)
                {

                     System.out.println("I foud One before "+array[j]); 


                }else
                {
                    break;
                }


            System.out.println("yes i found the array:"+array[i]);

        }

            for(int z=i;z>array.length;z++)
            {
                if(array[z]==1)
                {
                    System.out.println("I found after 3 is :"+array[z]);
                }
                break;
            }
    }
```

}